# Did people in Mahabharat era worshipped Lord Ram?

Tags: mahabharata, rama

Were there any references of Lord Ram, Lakshman and how he won over Ravan in Mahabharat to take as a learning in the time of Mahabharat?

I am asking this question due to a hidden question which goes like:

Did people in Mahabharat era worshipped Lord Ram and his idols?